# Java - Printing out the least occurring elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am given an array of size 10 and I want to write a program that prints out the elements that occur the least and the number of times they occur.

For example for the array: 1 2 3 3 2 2 4 4 5 4
The program should print.. Elements: 1 5, and the number of occurrences should be 1

What I have so far prints out the most occurrences and only prints out one element.

```
public class Question3 {

  public static void main (String[] args) { 

     int[] testarray = {1,2,3,3,2,2,4,4,5,4};
     int count = 0;
     int bigCount = 10;

      for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
          if(array[j] == array[i]) {
             count++;
        }
    }
        if(count > bigCount) {
          bigCount = count;
          array[i] = random;
      }
    }
 System.out.println("num of elements and occurences: " + maxCount);
  }
}
```

Comment: What I would do is use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` and increment the value for the key every time I come across a number. If it isn't in the list, add it and increment it by 1.

Comment: @Obicere, thanks for the reply, as I'm a beginner and still learning Java, I don't really understand what HashMap does. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Create a 2d array that matches the numbers with the number of occurrences (e.g. r[0][0] is the number and r[0][1] is the frequency).  Loop through the array and find the lowest occurrence frequency.  Then loop through again and print the numbers (r[0][0]) with a matching frequency (r[0][1]), then print the frequency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a data structure to hold each unique element and it's count, `Map<Integer,Integer>` is probably your best bet. Iterate over your array like you are right now, and keep the counts as you go. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = {1,2,3,3,2,2,4,4,5,4};
    //create the map like this: <Element,Count>
    Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    for (Integer i : array) {
        if (counts.get(i) == null) {
            counts.put(i, 1);
        } else {
            counts.put(i, counts.get(i) + 1);
        }
    }

    //find min value by sorting values and taking top element
    List<Integer> cs = new ArrayList<Integer>(counts.values());
    Collections.sort(cs);
    int minVal = cs.get(0);

    //find elements with minVal as their count
    List<Integer> minElements = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue() == minVal) {
            minElements.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    //spit out each element and the count
    for (Integer i : minElements) {
        System.out.println("Element: " + i + " Number of occurences: "
                + minVal);
    }

}
```

Not terribly efficient but it gets it done.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using another **array** to store the least ocurring elements. This array will be of length *equal* to the length of the "original" array (in case all elements appears just *one time*, all elements are the least ocurring):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4 };
    int count = 0;
    int maxCount = 10;
    int[] results = new int[array.length];
    int k = 0; // To keep index in 'results'

    // Initializing 'results', so when printing, elements that -1 are not part of the result
    // If your array also contains negative numbers, change '-1' to another more appropriate
    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        results[i] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == array[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count <= maxCount) { // <= so it admits number with the SAME number of occurrences
            maxCount = count;
            results[k++] = array[i]; // Add to 'results' and increase counter 'k'
        }
        count = 0; // Reset 'count'
    }

    // Printing result
    for (int i : results) {
        if (i != -1) {
            System.out.println("Element: " + i + ", Number of occurences: " + maxCount);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Element: 1, Number of occurences: 1
Element: 5, Number of occurences: 1
```

**Edit/Note:**

As @Happy commented, your program complexity is bad **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** because of the nested `for` loop. You could think in another way of doing this.

Comment: Please if you write a full code for him, do not keep a O(n²) algorithm.

Comment: @Happy I didn't touch his algorithm, just added and explained the "requested" part, but I added a *note* at the end of the answer.

Comment: I gave him steps to build a O(n) algorithm in my answer, I hope he will try this, the best way to learn. But thank you for the edit, you did good.

Comment: @Christian, I don't get what you mean by program complexity being O(n^2)?

Comment: @Happy What do you mean by program complexity being O(n^2)?

Comment: @user2980566 Search on Google about "Asymptotic complexity" and "Big O Notation". In few words, `n` is the length of the array, and because of the nested `for` loops (dependent of `n` because of the condition) the complexity is **O(n^2)**. If you had just one `for`, complexity would be **O(n)**. Is a way to measure in how much will increase the time your program will run, when a variable (input, in your case `array.length`) increases.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store all the elements you find in your if statement (with some adjusting), instead of only one element as you're currently do.

**Edit:**

There are three steps:

- Find how many each element occurs in the array. You can use a `Map<Integer, Integer>`, storing the elements as key and number of the element in the array as value. 
  You can use follow that piece of code:

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> v = new HashMap<>();
v.put(theElementOfTheArray, theNumberItAppears);
```

- Find the smaller value in your `Map`, using `Map.EntrySet()`
- Keep the elements which the value is equal to the result of step 2.

I wrote the algorithm but I prefer let you try. Do not hesitate if you have other questions.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, can you elaborate

Comment: Take a look on my edit, I'm getting you a way to write a better algorithm which is working to do what you want.